# Why does Neovim load from both .config/nvim/ and .local/share/nvim/?

Tags: neovim

Neovim will load configuration from `~/.config/nvim/`, and it also loads configuration found in `~/.local/share/nvim/site/` . In contrast, Vim loads configuration from `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim/` , it doesn't seem to load from more than one directory.

Why is there two directories that Neovim will load from? What's the difference between them? Where should I place my configuration and my packages, in the first one or the second one? What is the `site` directory about?

Comment: Technically, configuration can come from any directory in `runtimepath` by way of the `plugin` and other directories. It's only the vimrc that has a limited number of possible places.

Comment: Help me understand why Neovim is set up this way by default. Why load from both `.local/share/nvim/site` and from `.config/nvim/` ? Isn't this default confusing to users?